# Calculating AVG with SQL limited to last 10 rows and grouped by a field in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following layout:

```
CREATE TABLE uploads ( 
    id      INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                        NOT NULL,
    user    CHAR( 32 )  NOT NULL,
    score   INTEGER     NOT NULL,
);
```

I am attempting to calculate the average of the most recent 10 scores for each user.

I have tried a multitude of different SQL queries all of which don't seem to even get close to working, so I won't paste any of them here :(

The following query works for getting the average for a single user, but i can't get it to work grouped by the user column or by doing a correlated subquery based on the user field.

select avg(score) from (select score from upload where user="TEST" order by id limit 10)

Comment: Please post one or two of the "multitude" of SQL queries that were closest to that which you are looking for. This shows effort and allows for an explanation of why approach X didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I am not positive this works in SQLite, but this is a standardish SQL way of getting this result:

```
select u.*
       (select avg(score*1.0) from (select * from uploads u2 where u2.user = u.user order by id desc limit 10)) as avg10
from uploads u
```

Dems makes a good point.  To get one row for each user, you might do:

```
select u.user,
       (select avg(score*1.0) from (select * uploads u2 where u2.user = u.user order by id desc limit 10) t) as avg10
from (select distinct user
      from uploads
     ) u
```

I'm putting the distinct inside a subquery so the subquery in the SELECT is not evaluated too many times.  A user table is also a good idea instead of the subquery.

Comment: I'd make the outer query `FROM users`, assumin such a table exists.

Comment: Having the AVG inside that subquery seems to still give the average of all rows matching user, despite the limit. If I change the limit, or completely remove it, the avg is the same.

Comment: @TroyHeron . . . Yes, you are right.  I fixed the code so the limit is inside a subquery.  In the original version, it would return the first 10 averages, rather than the average of the first ten.